# SyncFramework upgrade from 1.0 to 2.0 Sql Server CE database change tracking issue

Tags: sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm trying to upgrade an application that uses Sync Framework 1.0 to synchronise a SqlServerCe database with SqlServer 2005. On the client, the existing database already has change tracking enabled, but when the sync is initiated SyncFramework 2.0 fails to find the last Sync Received anchor and then tries to re=initialize the Change tracking, which fails.

I get the exception...

```
{System.Exception} = {"The specified change tracking operation is not supported. To carry out this operation on the table, disable the change tracking on the table, and enable the change tracking."}
```

It seems like all I can do is delete the local database and recreate it. Which is not a great solution for us, since some of the data in the clients database is not synced with the server, and our users would prefer not to loose this data in the upgrade.

Is there any reason why SyncFramework 2.0 cannot locate the existing Last received sync anchor?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried installing Sync Framework 1.0 SP1 ? (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=b4f54dd0-5b66-4043-9b50-b12604bfcf35)

The VS 2010 designer still uses v1. SQL Compact SP2 exposes the change tracking API and the Sync Fx V1 SP1 updates Sync Fx to use this API.

Comment: I did install SP1 with no success.  The issue more so had to do with mixing my remote and server providers incorrectly.